# Stepping through code is slow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Using VS2008 with the latest patches.  Compared to a co-worker with a lower-end machine and half as much memory, stepping through the code in VS2008 on my box is really slow.  There is at least a perceptible 0.5 second delay for each line.

What can I do to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

Right click in your watch window.  Is the "Show Threads In Source" option enabled?  I accidentally enabled that somehow, and it slowed down debugging enough to be annoying.

Have you tried forcing a full rebuild?  If you're using the edit-and-continue or minimal rebuild options, I think some metadata files can grow larger over time rather than being rebuild from scratch.  You might also try deleting the NCB file for the solution.

Comment: Nope, the option is not enabled.  Plus, there are no .ncb files anywhere in the solution directory.

Comment: NCB files are only created for C++ projects, however yes that was my first thought too. I used to have a batch file in my windows startup folder to delete that stupid file.

Comment: True, but the question doesn't say what language is being used.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to one of my colleagues and cleaning the solution didn't work. He fixed it by deleting the source directory and getting a fresh checkout from subversion.
(which was lucky for him because he was this close to reinstalling VS)

So reading into that, I guess there was some obscure output file that was causing the slowdown.

You could try copying your solution and all your source files to a different directory, leaving behind all the bin and obj files, and seeing if that makes any difference.

If it still happens, create a brand new solution and see if it's still slower than your friend.
If so then a VS reinstall might be in order. And I feel your pain, that's at least 3hrs down the swanny.